# Days to update Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I have a prestashop shop that uses social login. And a few days ago when the customer tries to log in this message appears.

> You cannot login to this application because it does not comply with
> Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.
>
> If you are the developer of the app, please register the redirect URI
> in the Google Cloud Console.

I have edited the redirect address, as I didn't have a secure link, I had the same address, but http instead of https.

I changed the address a few days ago, but I still get the same message and the old, unsecured address.

The message when changing the url indicated that it could take minutes or hours, but it has been several days and the address has not been updated.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using Google OAuth for OpenID login, you have 2 levels of configuring your redirect URI.

- Configure the allowed redirect URIs in your OAuth credentials screen in the Google cloud console.
- Configure the same redirect URI in your application which sends the authorization request. Your authorization request should comprise of the same redirect URI.

As you mentioned, you might have updated your OAuth credential redirect URIs in console, but your app might be sending authorization response with the old URL itself. So, it will get rejected.

And yes, make sure the URI is an exact match. AFAIK, even a trailing slash can create problems.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the problem. My app was sending the old url. Solved!!!